# How do I know which data structure is in use?

Tags: memory, data-structures, operating-system, cpu, distributed-computing

I am naive about distributed systems. I want to know which data structure is in use. Assuming that its a shared Memory & CPU, when multiple programs are running, how can I know which data structure is in use?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you’re asking? There are many data structure used by distributed systems. Which ones are you interested in learning more about?

Comment: Basically the java.util.{Queue, Set, List, Map} ADTs

Comment: Barring running a test that checks the inputs and outputs, I don't see how this can be done without access to the bytecode.